# Structured street address from Android contacts

Tags: java, android

I need to get valid pieces from a street address from a contact on Android. The code I currently have was build for Android 2 and it already returns data. But the pieces from the street address for e.g. StructuredPostal.STREET, StructuredPostal.CITY, StructuredPostal.ZIP are mixed up. I assume the data I get back is based on the assumption that the address entered in the Contacts app has the style of a US american address. But the app will mostly be used in european countries where the structure of written down address is different. Hence the address pieces I get back do not help me.

A german address e.g. is usually built like:

```
<street name> <house number>
<zip code> <city>
<country>
```

The result is that I get the whole street address as a string with linebreak for StructuredPostal.Street and the other fields are empty.

The app using this code is largely updated and will only be running on Android 4 and above. Are there any changes in Android 4 that help with my problem? Or am I missing something at all?

Or are there any 3rd Party/Open Source libraries that help with this?
I only found a lot of questions here, but no answer that would me. It seems that people are only using this for addresses that have US style. Of course I could write e.g. addresses this way, but I need to understand the addresses that are in the contacts already.